# How to get the first column values in the wikipedia table using python bs4?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to web scrape a data table in wikipedia using python bs4. But I'm stuck with this problem. When getting the data values my code is not getting the first column or index zero. I feel there something wrong with the index but I can't figure it out. Please help. See the

[image]

```
response_obj = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_Manila').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response_obj,'lxml')
Neighborhoods_MM_Table = soup.find('table', {'class':'wikitable sortable'})

rows = Neighborhoods_MM_Table.select("tbody > tr")[3:8]

cities = []
for row in rows:
    city = {}
    tds = row.select('td')
    city["City or Municipal"] = tds[0].text.strip()
    city["%_Population"] = tds[1].text.strip()
    city["Population"] = float(tds[2].text.strip().replace(",",""))
    city["area_sqkm"] = float(tds[3].text.strip().replace(",",""))
    city["area_sqm"] = float(tds[4].text.strip().replace(",",""))
    city["density_sqm"] = float(tds[5].text.strip().replace(",",""))
    city["density_sqkm"] = float(tds[6].text.strip().replace(",",""))

    cities.append(city)

print(cities)

df=pd.DataFrame(cities)

df.head()
```

Comment: Please provide an [mre]

Comment: You've to post your code as a `code`, not a `picture`, so we can manually verify and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    target = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in soup.findAll(
        "td", style="text-align:right") if "%" in item.text] + [""]
    df = pd.read_html(r.content, header=0)[5]
    df = df.iloc[1: -1]
    df['Population (2015)[3]'] = target
    print(df)
    df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)


main("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_Manila")
```

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/8d302ff536a1595dc08a1c50c658dd4a/data.csv)

[image]